# Automaton for match ranges {min, max} in regular expression

Tags: regex, regular-language, finite-automata, dfa

Modern regular expression has operations like this `x{n,m}` which means pattern `x` repeats from `n` up to `m` times. Definition of regular language doesn't contain this operation but we can rewrite `x{n,m}` in the form `x^n|x^(n+1)|...|x^m`. Suppose `m` and `n` are large numbers (for example `10^9`) and we can't build an automaton for `x^n|x^(n+1)|...|x^m` because it has a large number of states. How improve automaton for support `x{n,m}` regular expression?

Comment: You'll find there's no limit to the number of states a DFA can have, as long as it's finite. More practically, though, for the sake of implementation on physical computers, use a counter variable.

Comment: @Welbog Yes, my question about implementation details on physical computer. If use a counter variable we can't convert NFA to DFA?

Comment: As far as I could think of, it can be further rewritten as `x{n}(x(x(...)?)?)?`. Then maybe we can use an FA-equivalent binary exponentiation algorithm for the `x{n}` part.